# Appengine connected Android prj got 404 on mobile test

Tags: android, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-endpoints

I got my android+appengine application (endpoint) up and running, everything works fine on my local machine, so I decided to upload my appengine code so that I can try accessing data through the Android application directly on my mobile phone.

When I try to call to my appengine backend, I got 404 error.

On browser if I try to call for http://[myAppID].appspot.com/_ah/spi I get:

```
Error: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

So the main serlvet is responding, what am I doing wrong??

(Permission for Internet granted!)

Thanks in advance!!

here's the code, this is executed inside an AsyncTask:

```
        Builder endpointBuilder = new Myendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
            }
        });

        Myendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).build();

        try {

            MyUsers result = endpoint.searchMyUser(params[0]).execute();

            return result.getItems().get(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

This is the code inside CloudEnpointUtils (obviously LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN is set to false) :

```
public static <B extends GoogleClient.Builder> B updateBuilder(B builder) {
    if (LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN) {
        builder.setRootUrl(LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL + "/_ah/api/");
    }
    // only enable GZip when connecting to remote server
    final boolean enableGZip = builder.getRootUrl().startsWith("https:");
    builder.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest jsonHttpRequest) {
            jsonHttpRequest.setEnableGZipContent(enableGZip);
        }
    });
    return builder;
}
```

I add the logcat for error:

```
10-04 11:40:22.770 W/System.err(13564): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
10-04 11:40:22.770 W/System.err(13564): Not Found
10-04 11:40:22.775 W/System.err(13564):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.executeUnparsed(GoogleClient.java:279)
10-04 11:40:22.775 W/System.err(13564):     at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:207)
10-04 11:40:22.775 W/System.err(13564):     at com.appspot.api.services.myuserendpoint.Myuserendpoint$SearchMyUser.execute(Myuserendpoint.java:702)
10-04 11:40:22.775 W/System.err(13564):     at it.my.my.app.core.MyBusinessDelegate$MyUserGetter.doInBackground(MyBusinessDelegate.java:303)
10-04 11:40:22.775 W/System.err(13564):     at it.my.my.app.core.MyBusinessDelegate$MyUserGetter.doInBackground(MyBusinessDelegate.java:1)
10-04 11:40:22.780 W/System.err(13564):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-04 11:40:22.780 W/System.err(13564):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-04 11:40:22.780 W/System.err(13564):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-04 11:40:22.780 W/System.err(13564):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-04 11:40:22.785 W/System.err(13564):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-04 11:40:22.785 W/System.err(13564):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-04 11:40:22.785 W/System.err(13564):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

EDIT: AppEngine DeployLog

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

 Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at:  'C:\Users\XXXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1884750854541661749.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 1 static files.
    Cloning 66 application files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 0 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.

Verifying availability:
    Will check again in 1 seconds.
    Will check again in 2 seconds.
    Will check again in 4 seconds.
    Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.

Updating datastore:
    Uploading index definitions.

Deployment completed successfully
```

EDIT2: other infos

I've tried to communicate with a java servlet I've put in appengine war, via browser there's no problem everything is working fine, if I try to ping from command line or try to communicate programmatically I have this error:

```
"Unable to resolve host "[myappID].appspot.com": No address associated with  hostname"
```

Please anybody help me find a solution

EDIT 3:
Good news, I've been able to call my servlet using the appengine address with version that is:

```
http://[version].[myAppID].appspot.com/myServlet
```

instead of:

```
http://[myAppID].appspot.com/myServlet
```

I don't know why but this way it'works! Still no luck trying to call remote appengine app via endpoint even using version-address trick, hope this help!

Comment: show your client code, please

Comment: Have you been acepted to the Trusted Tester program for cloud endpoints? If not the appengine project will not be accepted when uploading it. You can check the appengine console to see how the appengine project upload went

Comment: Hi my project uploads correctly and I can see the web part correctly on browser

Comment: How can I see if I've been accpted as Trusted Tester?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that the version being used in your code is different from the app engine default version.

The app engine default version is deployed to:
http://[appversion]-your-product-id.appspot.com
The code you are running though has specified the deployment version as 1 which means when deployed, your app will check here:
http://1-dot-your-project-id.appspot.com hence the 404 (because in essence, this URL doesn't exit. I use one here for illustration purposes).

To resolve this, go to https://appengine.google.com/deployment?app_id=s~your-project-id and make the version you've uploaded the default version

More here:
 [App Engine Set-up hiccups](http://kakoma.ug/code/2014/02/android-dev-tutorial-setting-app-engine-connected-app-hiccups/)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have not been accepted to the trusted tester program.  This will not work unless you are in the TT program.
You can sign up at this page:

http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/

You will receive an email when(if) accepted.

Comment: I think you are wrong. The FAQ says "How do I get access to Endpoints?
A: Join the trusted testers group, which will grant you access to the documentation. No further signups or approvals are required.". PS: I'm having the same problem

Comment: The link now says "Google Cloud Endpoints
Now available to everyone!"